# Simple technique to upsample/interpolate video features?

Tags: signal-processing, interpolation, hidden-markov-models

I'm trying to analyse audio and visual features in tandem. My audio speech features are mel-frequency cepstrum co-efficients sampled at 100fps using the Hidden Markov Model Toolkit. My visual features come from a lip-tracking programme I built and are sampled at 29.97fps.

I know that I need to interpolate my visual features so that the sample rate is also 100fps, but I can't find a nice explanation or tutorial on how to do this online. Most of the help I have found comes from the speech recognition community which assumes a knowledge of interpolation on behalf of the reader, i.e. most cover the step with a simple "interpolate the visual features so that the sample rate equals 100fps".

Can anyone pooint me in the right direction?

Thanks a million

Comment: This question might be a better fit for http://dsp.stackexchange,com, since it's really about signal processing rather than programming *per se*.

Answer (score 1):

Since face movement is not low-pass filtered prior to video capture, most of the classic DSP interpolation methods may not apply.  You might as well try linear interpolation of your features vectors to get from one set of time points to a set at a different set of time points.  Just pick the 2 closest video frames and interpolate to get more data points in between.  You could also try spline interpolation if your facial tracking algorithm measures accelerations in face motion.

Comment: Thank you :-) I will give your suggestion a try :-)